# ¿Cómo agregar elementos a una List<Appointment>?

Tags: c#, csv, lista

Les muestro parte de mi código...

```
//Creo mi variable
List<Appointment> ListFolder = new List<Appointment>();

//Creo mi objeto
Appointment appointment = new Appointment();

//Recorro un archivo CSV, voy extrayendo la información que necesito y se la asigno a una variable de mi clase Appointment
var values = line.Split(',');
appointment.folder = values[0];
appointment.title = values[1];

//Y trato de llenar el List< Appointment> de la siguiente forma
ListFolder.Add(appointment.folder, appointment.title);
```

Pero me marca un error:

> "No overload for method 'Add' takes 2 arguments"

y si le pongo solo un argumento me dice:

> "The best overload method match for 'List< Appointment>.Add(Appointment)' has some invalid arguments"

Mis dudas son, ¿cómo elimino esos errores y cómo puedo llenar ese tipo de List?

Comment: Creas una lista de `Appointment` asi que en el `add` has de añadir un `Appointment`. Quedaria: `ListFolder.Add(appointment);` (y las variables en minusculas, si no parecen clases xD)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu lista acepta objetos del tipo `Appointment`. Asi que simplemente debes añadir el objeto que acabas de crear:

```
Appointment appointment = new Appointment();
var values = line.Split(',');
appointment.folder = values[0];
appointment.title = values[1];
ListFolder.Add(appointment);
```

Comment: dandote upvote a ti, es como si me lo diera a mi comentario ;)

Comment: Yo se lo di a tu comentario. Me ganaste por segundos @lois6b ;)

Answer (score 3):

Tienes que añadir el objeto appointment directamente de esta manera.

```
ListFolder.Add(appointment);
```

sino lo que estas intentando hacer es añadir a la Lista ListFolder los atributos del objeto appointment

Answer (score 1):

Estas usando una lista genérica que acepta objetos del tipo *Appointment*
como ya mencionaron tienes que usar el método Add() con un objeto tipo Appointment

Hay varias formas de construir un objeto como de inicializar una colección aquí unas de ellas ; Checa mi ejemplo en [github](https://github.com/jahbenjah/misrespuestasSOes/blob/master/Appointment/Program.cs)

1. Usando LINQ
2. Usando inicializadores de colecciones ;
3. La forma "regular" :

   List ap1 = new List();

   ```
        // agregando el objeto tipo Appointment
        // Contructor por defualt y propiedades autoimplementadas
        Appointment ap = new Appointment();
        ap.Title = "T";
        ap.Folder ="F";

        ap1.Add(ap);
        ap1.Add(new Appointment());
        ap1.Add(new Appointment(){Title="Title 1 ",Folder="Folder 1"});

        // Usando inicializadores de colecciones :

        List<Appointment> cats = new List<Appointment>
           {
               new Appointment(){ Title = "Title", Folder="Folder" },
               new Appointment(){ Title = "Title", Folder="Folder" },
               new Appointment(){ Title = "Title", Folder="Folder" }
           };


        // Lenando la lista con los datos de un archvio csv  usando Linq .

         List<Appointment>  appointmnet = File.ReadAllLines("Appointment.csv")
                               .Skip(1)   // No considera  la linea de encabezados
                               .Select(MakeAppointment) // 
                               .ToList();

                               foreach(var a in appointmnet)
                               Console.WriteLine(a);

       }
   ```